# XSL, using XML as parameter to template

Tags: xml, xslt, templates

Is it OK to pass XML to an XSL template through a parameter? For example, below I have the template `body` call template `test1` which passes some XML through the parameter `var1`. I then attempt to walk to the node `a` using XPATH

```
<xsl:template name="test1">
    <xsl:param name="var1" />
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="$var1/a" />
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="body">
    <xsl:call-template name="test1">
        <xsl:with-param name="var1" >
            <a>foo</a>
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is, this causes my XSL interpreter to fail with an unuseful error message. I'm being forced to use a closed source vendor system for generating documents, so I'm not able to debug. But before I look into it more, I'm looking for confirmation that this is valid usage of XSL.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a detailed explanation and solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:template name="body"> 
>     <xsl:call-template name="test1"> 
>         <xsl:with-param name="var1" > 
>             <a>foo</a> 
>         </xsl:with-param> 
>     </xsl:call-template> 
> </xsl:template>
> ```

The `$var1` parameter passed to the template is hardly usable in XSLT 1.0/XPath 1.0 due to the infamous RTF (Result-Tree Fragment) type.

**From the [W3C XSLT 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Result-Tree-Fragments)**.:

> 11.1 Result Tree Fragments
>
> Variables introduce an additional data-type into
>   the expression language. This
>   additional data type is called result
>   tree fragment. A variable may be bound
>   to a result tree fragment instead of
>   one of the four basic XPath data-types
>   (string, number, boolean, node-set). A
>   result tree fragment represents a
>   fragment of the result tree. A result
>   tree fragment is treated equivalently
>   to a node-set that contains just a
>   single root node. However, the
>   operations permitted on a result tree
>   fragment are a subset of those
>   permitted on a node-set. **An
>   operation is permitted on a result
>   tree fragment only if that operation
>   would be permitted on a string (the
>   operation on the string may involve
>   first converting the string to a
>   number or boolean). In particular, it
>   is not permitted to use the `/`, `//`,
>   and `[]` operators on result tree
>   fragments. When a permitted operation
>   is performed on a result tree
>   fragment, it is performed exactly as
>   it would be on the equivalent
>   node-set.**
>
> When a result tree fragment is copied
>   into the result tree (see [11.3 Using
>   Values of Variables and Parameters
>   with xsl:copy-of]), then all the nodes
>   that are children of the root node in
>   the equivalent node-set are added in
>   sequence to the result tree.
>
> Expressions can only return values of
>   type result tree fragment by
>   referencing variables of type result
>   tree fragment or calling extension
>   functions that return a result tree
>   fragment or getting a system property
>   whose value is a result tree fragment.

To circumvent this crippling design decision, almost every XSLT processor has its own extension function, usually named `xxx:node-set()` where the `xxx` prefix must be bound to a vendor-defined namespace.

**Solution**:

Find exactly what is the name of this extension function offered by your XSLT processor vendor.

Or, if your XSLT processor supports [**EXSLT**](http://exslt.org), use the **[`exsl:node-set()`](http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html)** extension function as defined by EXSLT.

Here are some vendor-specific namespaces:

**MSXML and .NET XslCompiledTransform, XslCompiledTransform**:

```
xmlns:vendor="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
```

**Xalan** (note, the function name is: `xxx:nodeset()` !):

```
 xmlns:vendor="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
```

**Saxon (6.x):**

```
 xmlns:vendor="http://icl.com/saxon"
```

**Altova:**

```
 xmlns:vendor="http://www.altova.com/xslt-extensions"
```

**All XSLT processors that implement EXSLT**:

```
xmlns:vendor="http://exslt.org/common"
```

---

In case the body of the `<xsl:param>` isn't dynamically constructed, one can avoid the

`xxx:node-set()` function in the following way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfparamXML">
   <a>
     <b>foo</b>
   </a>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vparamXML" select=
 "document('')/*/xsl:variable
                [@name='vrtfparamXML']/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:copy-of select="$vparamXML/b"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the result is the wanted child of the RTF**:

```
<b xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">foo</b>
```

**Note**: XSLT 2.0/XPath 2.0 got rid of the RTF "type" and there one doesn't have any problem accessing temporary trees and navigating them using the full power of XPath 2.0

Comment: I appreciate your thorough response Dimitre. I will contact my vendor and see if such an extension is possible.

Comment: @Mike: You are welcome. For your convenience I edited my answer to provide the namespaces some of the most XSLT processors use.

Comment: I found that my processor includes support for exsl. Thanks again for your help, this will allow me to greatly improve my design

Comment: I am using xslt 2.0, passing xml with xsl:with-param and reading in template does not work. When i read with xsl:param tag its converted to single string with xml tags removed.

Comment: @Naveen this is not a question, but a statement. Please, ask a SO question and provide all relevant details. Then ping me via a comment and I will be happy to help.